# Angular: Multiple nested named routing outlets, navigation not working

Tags: angular

In my Angular application I have some complex screens that I want to make independent of each other and also lazy loadable, and for that I am using named router outlets. When there was a main router outlet, and inside it a named one, everything worked well. But now I have a case with a tabbed screen, and each tab opens a screen with another tabs.

Each level is lazy loaded. The main screen that is loaded in the main router-outlet of the application is loaded like this

```
 path: 'firstTabbedScreen',
 loadChildren: () => import('@modules/firstTabbed.module').then((m) => m.FirstTabbedModule),
```

The FirstTabbedModule has the following routings:

```
const outlet = 'firstTabbedOutlet';
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppMainScreen,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('@modules/secondTabbed.module').then((m) => m.SecondTabbedModule),
        pathMatch: 'full',
        outlet,
      },
      {
        path: 'secondTabbed',
        loadChildren: () => import('@modules/secondTabbed.module').then((m) => m.SecondTabbedModule),
        outlet,
      },
      {
        path: 'changeSecondTabbed',
        loadChildren: () => import('@modules/changeSecondTabbed.module').then((m) => m.ChangeSecondTabbedModule),
        outlet,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Inside the "AppMainScreen" component html there is a <router-outlet name="firstTabbedOutlet" that loads the children routes above.

The SecondTabbedModule has its own routing that looks like this

```
const outlet = 'secondTabbedOutlet';
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppMainSecondScreen,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('@modules/thirdTabbed.module').then((m) => m.ThirdTabbedModule),
        pathMatch: 'full',
        outlet,
      },
      {
        path: 'thirdTabbed',
        loadChildren: () => import('@modules/thirdTabbed.module').then((m) => m.ThirdTabbedModule),
        outlet,
      },
      {
        path: 'changeThirdTabbed',
        loadChildren: () => import('@modules/changeThirdTabbed.module').then((m) => m.ChangeThirdTabbedModule),
        outlet,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Inside the "AppMainSecondScreen" component html there is a <router-outlet name="secondTabbedOutlet" that loads the children routes above.

The ThirdTabbedModule has its own routing that looks like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
   {
     path: '',
     component: AppMainThirdScreen,
   },
];
```

So the navigation works perfectly by default, if nothing is clicked to trigger it.
The default router outlet will load "AppMainScreen", the "firstTabbedOutlet" will load "AppMainSecondScreen" and the "secondTabbedOutlet" will load "AppMainThirdScreen", here being over. The problem arrives at trying to change between routes.

While by default all the screens will display perfectly, and the route in the navbar will look like

```
http://localhost:4200/absoluteParent/firstTabbedScreen
```

And the following navigation to navigate between the first named router outlet routes works perfectly

```
 this.router.navigate(['absoluteParent/firstTabbedScreen', { outlets: { firstTabbedOutlet: 'changeSecondTabbed'} }]);
```

The following navigation DOES NOT WORK, instead changing the first named router outlet to the route mentioned inside the first outlets object, even if the URL in the navbar changes. The page does not navigate to changeThirdTabbed in the second named router outlet, instead refreshing firstTabbedOutlet with changeSecondTabbed, and navigating in the secondTabbedOutlet to the "" route.

```
this.router.navigate([
  'absoluteParent/firstTabbedScreen',
  { outlets: { firstTabbedOutlet: ['changeSecondTabbed', { outlets: { secondTabbedOutlet: ['changeThirdTabbed'] } }] } },
]);
```

What am I doing wrong here and how can I make this three levels lazy loaded navigation work?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), ideally in an online code editor such as [Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com).